# How can you make a dropdown slide-down animation in ng-bootstrap using Angular Animations or using css?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to animate the dropdown menu of ng-bootstrap using Angular Animations, and while the animation is working pretty well in development, in production when the menu opens it jumps from top to bottom of the dropdown for some reason. Here is my code:

animation:

```
   trigger('openClose', [
        transition('closed => open', [
            style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-30px)'}),
            animate('100ms ease-out',
                style({opacity: '*', transform: 'translateY(0)'}))
        ]),
        transition('open => closed', [
            style({ opacity: '*', transform: 'translateY(0)'}),
            animate('100ms ease-out',
                style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-30px)'}))
        ])
    ])
```

component:

```
<div  ngbDropdown 
      class="d-inline-block w-100">

 <!-- dropdown button -->
 <button class="dropdown-button btn btn-icon-right"
      type="button"
      ngbDropdownToggle>
  <span>
    <span>my title</span>
  </span>
 </button>

 <!-- dropdown menu -->
 <div  ngbDropdownMenu 
      class="dropdown-menu" 
      [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'">
  my content
 </div>
</div>
```

The animation on closing is also not working. I've tried animating on `:enter` and `:leave` and `void`, they're not working either. Any idea where the problem might be, or how to animate ngbDropdown properly? And is there a way to animate it using css only?

Solution: The problem is that in production for some reason the dropdown-menu is set using `transform: translateY(0)`, while in dev it's set using `top: 0`. So to make a slide-down animation you have to use `top` in prod, and `transform` in dev. To solve that I had to override the `dropdown-menu` with my own class. Here's a hacky solution using css, until the ngbootstrap team adds animations:

HTML:

```
<div  ngbDropdown 
      class="dropdown"
      (openChange)="openChange($event)"
      #dropdown>

  <!-- dropdown button -->
  <button class="dropdown-button btn"
          [ngClass]="buttonClass"
          [disabled]="disabled"
          type="button"
          ngbDropdownToggle>
    <span> My Title   </span>
  </button>

  <!-- dropdown menu -->
  <div  ngbDropdownMenu 
        class="dropdown-menu2" // this is important to override the ngb class
        [ngClass]="dropdownOpenClass"
        #dropdownMenu>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.dropdown-menu2 {
    display:block;
    visibility: collapse;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    top: 0 !important;
    &.dd-closed {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(20px) !important; // overwrite prod on closed
    }
    &.dd-open {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(38px);
    }
}
```

TS:

```
dropdownOpenClass = 'dd-closed';

openChange(e: Event) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.dropdownOpenClass = this.isOpen ? 'dd-open' : 'dd-closed';
    this.openChanged.emit(e);
}
```

**Update:** The workaround above doesn't work in 4.1.0+. If anyone has a solution then please post it below.

Answer (score 0):

Working on '*a way to animate it using css only*'... we had to work around default bootstrap classes:

- the dropdown-menu class from bootstrap which keeps the drop-down hidden by default
- the show class which reveals the drop-down
- we had to take this in our hands, which we did using ngStyle
- we also created classes for slow reveal and slow hide... to toggle these, we create a variable and used ngClass
- to tune the duration effects, you can change these classes to get the exact effect that you want

**HTML**

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle (click)="dropDownClicked()">Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div 
  [ngStyle]="ddStyling? {'display': 'block'} : {'display': 'block'}"
  [ngClass]='ddStatus' ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ddOpened{
  background:lightpink;
  animation: myOpenMove 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes myOpenMove {
  0% {  visibility:hidden; opacity: 0; }
  100% { visibility:visible; opacity: 1; }
}

.ddClosed{
  background:lightpink;
  animation: myCloseMove 1s ease-in;
  transform: translate(0px, 38px);
  visibility:hidden;
}

@keyframes myCloseMove {
  0% { opacity: 1 !important; visibility: visible; }
  100% {  height:1px; opacity: 0; visibility:hidden; }
}
```

working [demo on stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5plko)

Comment: Normal animations work for me, but using `transform: translate(x,y)` makes the menu jumpy. I noticed that there's a `translate(0px, 38px)` in my production build attached as an attribute, but not in my dev build. You also added a translate to your code. What's the reason for that? And any idea where it's from in ngbootstrap's code?

Comment: If you open the default bootstrap code in chrome developer tools, you'll see that 'translate(0px, 38px)' was put in to place the drop down menu just below the drop down toggle button